# Custom Autocomplete with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on jquery autocomplete custom data and display.I want to display some static dropdown on keypress in textbox.when user select that list item i want to add it to textbox.

the code which i have tested is

```
 $('#uinput').keyup(function() {
        var val = $('#uinput').val();
        if(val.length>1) {  // check length

                // handle successful DWR response
                //alert(data);

                var b=[{value: "jquery-ui",
                    label: "jQuery UI",}];
                $('#uinput').autocomplete({source:b,

                      select: function( event, ui ) {
                          $( "#uinput" ).val( ui.item.label+"="+document.getElementById('uinput').value  );


                          return false;
                        }

                }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                    return $( "<li>" )
                    .data('item.autocomplete', item)
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "=" + document.getElementById('uinput').value + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
                };

        } else {
            $('#uinput').autocomplete([]);  // clean
        }
    });
```

For reference what i want to do
[custom autocomplete](http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/#demo)

Comment: Why don't you simply use `$('#uinput').autocomplete(a);`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Thanks for reply,but i want to show it for any input {a-z,1-9}

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please give an example which input you have, what should trigger the autocomplete and why the current implementation doesn't do what you need.

Comment: @AaronDigulla i have attached a link after question please have a look. I will separate all things,(1).I want to show a list of values on any input in textbox (2)I want to assign user selected value to textbox with user input attached to value in custom list

Comment: second requirement is working fine ,i have edited code now

Comment: You want to replicate the demo? Why can't you use the VisualSearch.js?

Comment: Because it is submitting the data of search box after enter button is pressed ,i have form with button to submit data.

Comment: Try `autosearch: false` as option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish but I think I've put together this example that I think might help you

https://jsfiddle.net/mgxnxhs8/5/

here's my javascript

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [{
        label: "jQuery 1.9.1",
        value: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js",
    }, {
        label: "jQuery 2.1.4",
        value: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js",
    }];
    $('#uinput').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        minLength: 0,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#uoutput').val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("search");
    });
});
```

The dropdown opens up when you enter the textbox and displays the "label" key of the tags.  On Select(), it sets the value of another textbox to the "value" key of the selected tag.

Let me know if theres something I missed. Hope this helps